# jsp pageEncoding and ContentType

Tags: java, jsp, character-encoding

I make my jsp file like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello
</body>
</html>
```

i didn't define contentType,only defined pageEncoding，then I saw the index_jsp.java, I find the code fragment like this:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

then I change the pageEncoding to "UTF-8"， I find the code fragment like this:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

why? I didn't difine the contentType, but result is use pageEncoding value, it is say that if I didn't defind the contentType in jsp, then the serlvet container use the pageEncoding for default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JSP directive affects the overall structure of the servlet that results from the JSP
page. The `page` directive lets you control the structure of the servlet by importing classes,
customizing the servlet superclass, setting the content type, and the like.  Unlike regular servlets, for which the default MIME type is `text/plain`, the default
for JSP pages is `text/html` (with a default character set of `ISO-8859-1`).